# Invariance of boundary proof attempt

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Problem:

Suppose $F:M\rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism between manifolds with boundary.
Then $F(\partial{M})=\partial{N}$.

My attempt:

Let $F(p)\in F(\partial{M})$ for $p\in \partial{M}$. This means for any chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$, $\phi(p)\in \partial{H^m}$. Choose any chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$.Let $(V,\psi)$ be any chart in $N$ about $F(p)$.

Then notice $\psi(F(p))=\psi(F(\phi^{-1}(\phi(p))=(\psi\circ F \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))$. As $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U\cap V)\rightarrow \psi(U\cap V)$ is a diffeomorphism, the result result follows from the following lemma:

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are open in $\mathbb{H}^n$ and $f:U\rightarrow V$ a diffeomorphism. Then if $p\in U$ is an interior point of $\mathbb{H}^n$, then $f(p)$ is an interior points of $\mathbb{H}^n$. Similarly if $p$ was a boundary point of $\mathbb{H}^n$.

For the converse, let $q\in \partial{N}$. By assumption, there exists a unique $p\in M$  such that $F(p)=q \iff F^{-1}(q)=p$. Since $F^{-1}$ is smooth, repeating the same argument above, the result follows.

is this correct?

Comment: It seems like the essence of the proof is the lemma. So can you prove it?

Comment: @Matematleta yup, the proof of the lemma is given in lectures.

Comment: yes, the proof is right